# Hashing with Google Guava in Java outputting with lowercase characters while online hashing site outputs in uppercase

Tags: java, hash, guava, sha256

I'm hashing a password in Java using google's `Hashing`.

```
password = Hashing
        .sha256()
        .hashString(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .toString();
```

When I pass any text to that line, it hashes and outputs everything with lowercase characters, for example, if I pass "foo", the value of `password` becomes:

```
2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae
```

However, if I use this [site](https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/) to hash "foo", the value it outputs is

```
2C26B46B68FFC68FF99B453C1D30413413422D706483BFA0F98A5E886266E7AE
```

As far as I can tell that's just the exact same password except with uppercase letters instead of lowercase.

What's causing those to output different values, and how can I get guava to output with uppercase letters (without just calling toUpperCase, unless that's really the only way)

Comment: They're hex digits, and case isn't semantically significant.

Comment: It is simply hex-encoding of binary data. Hex-encoding does not specify upper-/lower-case, because it doesn't matter to hex-encoding. If you compare the hex-encoded string, *you* need to do a case-insensitive comparison, or *you* need to standardize on either upper or lower case.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The explanation was really what I was asking for. I already knew I could just call toUpperCase

Answer (score 5):

The main reason why Guava is making the result string in lower case, is because of the implementation of: `com.google.common.hash.HashCode.toString()` [method](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.java#L413).

You can simply call `toUpperCase()` method, from `String` class, on your result hash string value:

```
password = Hashing
        .sha256()
        .hashString(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .toString()
        .toUpperCase();
```